# Using Charles web proxy with iPhone hotspot

Tags: iphone, proxy, http

I've been using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to sniff the requests that my iPhone is making for some time now. I've always got it to work by connecting both my iPhone and my MacBook to the same wireless network and then entering my computer's local IP address along with port number 8888 in the proxy settings in my iPhone. But, my internet is down and I need to use AT&T's hotspot on my iPhone for internet instead of my apartment's wireless.

After looking at my Mac's system preferences, it appears that I'm connected to the IP `127.0.0.1` with my Mac. Does anyone know if Charles can be used to sniff traffic with a person hotspot?